# How to make water wall effect?

Tags: workflow, fluid-simulation

Go you have any ideas how to make this sort of an effect? I've tried to achieve this using water simulation, but it didn't turned out well. Using a texture looks like rational, but I have no idea how to make one. I'm concerned that buying Flip Fluids is my only option.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you it for animation or still image?

Comment: I was wondering about quick camera zoom animation, but still image is fine

Comment: I have personally found fluid simulations to be poor at this. I think it would ideally use a glass BSDF with an animated displacement/normal map... but I don't know how to generate that map. Footage of the effect would be useful, and I haven't had much luck finding any.

Comment: Also, the nearest thing I've come across for creating this kind of effect is this After Effects tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLwpCNil3XE
It relies heavily on proprietary filters, but the general idea of making a black and white animation of the water's displacement seems like the right approach.

Comment: Possibly need to render a smoke effect? Then post process it to get harder edges and use it as a normal displace?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how this workflow should look like, could you please give me some more directions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using a Fluid simulation - although it does take a bit of trial and error to get the settings right whilst still being able to keep the simulation resolution low enough to make it practical.

[image: repeating animation]

To set up the scene you need the Fluid domain and the 'nozzles' to spray the water. The fluid domain should be kept as small as possible to reduce the computation for the simulation. Note that if you resize the domain you should always 'Apply Scale' for the resizing to take effect on the simulation cells (otherwise the simulation will be distorted).

I used the 'Shell' setting for the Inflow nozzles. This allows them to be defined as simple plane faces rather than a volume within the simulation. The sizing and orientation of the nozzles is quite significant - they need to be big enough in relation to the fluid 'resolution' and the direction of the 'Inflow' should approximately match the orientation of those faces.

[image: nozzles]
[image: Inflow settings]

The higher the Resolution of the fluid simulation the better - although larger values will significantly affect the simulation bake time. However, the resolution must be high enough in relation to your inflow nozzles so that each contributes a solid stream of fluid. If the inflow is intermittent, try larger nozzles, reorient the nozzles to match the flow direction, or increase the resolution.

Once you have the general flow working you will likely need to adjust the Inflow speed and direction (by changing the X,Y,Z Velocity settings) to adjust the flow. This needs to be high enough to produce enough fluid to cover the surface without being too high to cause splashing (which will hit the edges of your domain and look ugly). One trick to prevent splashing is to increase the compressibility of the fluid, allowing the fluid to spread into an area rather than bounce off the existing fluid (technically not physically accurate for water but produces better effects without having to drastically increase the domain resolution).

[image: domain settings]

For simplicity I used the back face of the domain as the 'surface' for the water wall rather than a fluid Obstacle. I added the 'fake' glass pane behind the domain for the final render - it doesn’t interact with the simulation. This simplifies the simulation as there are no complications of the collision surface not aligning with the cells of the simulation. Add an Outflow mesh to the bottom of the domain to drain away the fluid. Don't forget to set your domain mesh to 'Smooth' (or you'll get angular fluid).

[image: scene]

Bake the simulation and assign suitable fluid material (essentially just slightly coloured glass).

Here's the final result baked with a resolution of 300 :

[image: animated]

Blend file included [image]